# For executing multiple python scripts on multiple files in a directory: bash or python? (Just out of curiosity)

Tags: bash, python-2.7, directory

This is a question just out of curiosity. I have approximately 4000 files in a directory, and ~400 python scripts to run on each file. I used stackoverflow to learn to write a bash script that runs all the python scripts on all the files in parallel and generate corresponding outfiles (thanks guise!!). This past weekend, my brother-in-law helped me do the same thing, but with a python script. Both methods give the same result, but does it really matter if it's done with bash or with python, or is that just personal preference? What do you prefer, and why? I am a beginner with both python and bash shell scripting and found it more straightforward/faster to construct the bash script. Before I possibly fall into a bad practice and commit to spending more time learning one over the other, I just want to see what you guys think. Thanks!

Comment: There's no objective difference here, just personal preference, or maybe some consideration for future maintenance effort. For a workflow of various commands that have input files and output files, the nail-hammer tool would be Make: being purpose-built it would be out-of-the-box able to do things like avoid reprocessing when input files haven't changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned.. it is sort of personal preference and sort of a matter of what you mean by "does it really matter". As long as the task you're trying to get done (executing scripts on each file in a directory) gets done and you have no real performance requirements, then either way is fine.

I would guess that you would prefer the method that works the fastest for such a large job and I would guess that means that bash is the way to go (haven't benchmarked anything of the like myself). If you're looking for something like code readability, I would argue that Python is the way to go (although that depends on how you code in Python as well). Without any sort of factor to optimize for it doesn't matter.

As for what I prefer.. I'm way more comfortable with Python so I would pick Python over bash, but of course that depends on what you're more comfortable with and what you are actually trying to optimize for.